# Finding lowest value with no overlapping dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with criteria, a start and end date, and a value. The goal is to find the lowest value for each unique criteria and start date without overlapping dates (exclusive of end date). I made a pivot table to make it easier for myself but I know there is probably a way to highlight all valid rows that meet the above requirements with some formula or conditional formatting.

I have attached a google drive link where the spreadsheet can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUqU4f5HMGO-Jvvn9wV46GD9wcgEStSO8yNtloJsrls/edit?usp=sharing) and I have some images of the sheet as well. I know that it might be possible with conditional formatting but I just don't know how to combine everything I want it to do in a single formula.

Example below:

Row 2 is a valid entry because it has the lowest value for Item 1 starting on 03-15-2021, same with row 9.

Row 5 is valid because the start date does not fall within the date range of row 2 (exclusive of end date)

Row 7 is not valid because the start date is between the start and end date of row 6

[image: pivot table]

Comment: I think having both the pivot table and the data image is confusing, since they don't seem to agree.  If row 5 is valid in the pivot table, is that only because row 4 has no start date?  In the data view, why is row 4 valid - doesn't the start date fall within the date range of row 3?

Comment: I'm having trouble what the actual algorithm you are tying to describe is. Do you want the group with non-overlapping dates that has the smallest sum of values for each item? Or maybe it is the earliest starting date has precedence and then try to fit the rest and the value only is used if they start the same day?

Comment: @Martí I think you are right on the money about grouping the non-overlapping dates with the smallest values for each item. The values aren't sums they are just numbers that correspond to each 'item/start date' combination. So row 2-4 is a group of 3 'item 1/03-15-2021' data points and the one with the lowest value is selected. Based on the date range of the valid entry, row 5 is also valid. Hopefully, that provides a little bit of clarity.

Comment: I think I'm getting it. Just to be sure, if in item 1 we have 3 rows: [01-01 to 01-03 with value 10], [01-02 to 01-05 with value 1] and [01-03 to 01-04 with value 10]; I'd expect the first and the third to be selected. Is that right? If not, could you elaborate, please?

Comment: @Martí yes exactly, sorry I wasn't able to clearly verbalize what I am trying to do.

Comment: @LarryFlores This case is quite complex. How comfortable would you be about using Google Apps Script to make this validations?

Comment: @Martí I have little experience with Apps Script but I am open to it

Answer (score 1):

You may add a bounded script to your project. Then you can call it either with a picture/drawing that has the function assigned (button-like), or adding a menu to Google Sheets.

From what you said in the question and the comments, this seems to do what you are trying. Notice that this requires the V8 runtime (which should be the default).

```js
function validate() {
  // Get the correct sheet
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  
  // Get the data
  const length = sheet.getLastRow() - 1
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, length, 4)
  const rows = range.getValues()
  const data = Array.from(rows.entries(), ([index, [item, start, end, value]]) => {
    /*
     * Row               Index
     *  1   Criteria 1
     *  2   Item 1         0
     *  3   Item 1         1
     *  4   Item 1         2
     *
     * row = index + 2
     */
    return {
      row: index + 2,
      criteria: item,
      start: start.getTime(),
      end: end.getTime(),
      value: value
    }
  })
  
  
  // Sort the data by criteria (asc), start date (asc), value (asc) and end date (asc)
  data.sort((a, b) => {
    let order = a.criteria.localeCompare(b.criteria)
    if (order !== 0) return order
    
    order = a.start - b.start
    if (order !== 0) return order
    
    order = a.value - b.value
    if (order !== 0) return order
    
    order = a.end - b.end
    return order
  })
  
  
  // Iterate elements and extract the valid ones
  // Notice that because we sorted them, the first one of each criteria will always be valid
  const valid = []
  let currentCriteria
  let currentValid = []
  
  for (let row of data) {
    if (row.criteria !== currentCriteria) {
      // First of the criteria
      valid.push(...currentValid)    // Move the valids from the old criteria to the valid list
      currentValid = [row]           // The new list of valid rows is only the current one (for now)
      currentCriteria = row.criteria // Set the criteria
    } else {
      const startDateCollision = currentValid.some(valid => {
        row.start >= valid.start && row.start < valid.end
      })
      if (!startDateCollision) {
        currentValid.push(row)
      }
    }
    
  }
  valid.push(...currentValid)
  
  
  // Remove any old marks
  sheet.getRange(2, 5, length).setValue('')

  // Mark the valid rows
  for (let row of valid) {
    sheet.getRange(row.row, 5).setValue('Valid')
  }
}
```

### Algorithm rundown

1. We get the sheet that we have the data in. In this case we do it by name (remember to change it if it's not the default `Sheet1`)
2. We read the data and transform it in a more an array of objects, which for this case makes it easier to manage
3. We sort the data. This is similar to the transpose you made but in the code. It also forces a priority order and groups it by criteria
4. Iterate the rows, keeping only the valid:

   - We keep a list of all the valid ones (`valid`) and one for the current criteria only (`currentValid`) because we only have to check data collisions with the ones in the same criteria.
   - The first iteration will always enter the if block (because currentCriteria is `undefined`).
   - When changing criteria, we dump all the rows in `currentValid` into `valid`. We do the same after the loop with the last criteria
   - When changing criteria, the `CurrentValid` is an array with the current row as an element because the first row will always be valid (because of sorting)
   - For the other rows, we check if the starting date is between the starting and ending date of any of the valid rows for that criteria. If it's not, add it to this criteria's valid rows
5. We remove all the current "Valid" in the validity row and fill it out with the valids

The cornerstone of the algorithm is actually sorting the data. It allows us to not have to search for the best row, as it's always the next one. It also ensures things like that the first row of a criteria is always valid.

### Learning resources

- [Javascript tutorial (W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)
- [Google App Scripts](https://www.google.com/script/start/)
- [Overview of Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [Custom Menus in Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)

### Code references

- [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Sheet.getRange (notice the 3 overloads)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [let ... of (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [Spread syntax (...) (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Arrow function expressions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Array.from() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [Array.prototype.push() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [Array.prototype.sort() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Date.prototype.getTime() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)
- [String.prototype.localeCompare() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)